what are the best practices to use the BOM APIs in React component
The rules of react mentioned that a component and hook must be pure, which means it will render the same content with the same(props, state and context).
Then what about the BOM APIs, for example, location, what if I want to render different things based on the querystring

const Hello = () => {
  const name = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('name');
  return <div>hello, {name}</div>
}


Is this a pure component? if not, how to make it pure?

The most obvious question may be the following one:
What is the real reason for referring the global state location.search inside the function ?
The answer may be, this component is only targeting the current page in a Browser. It should not be used anywhere else. Therefore as long as the component has been used in the context it has been designed for, it would be very easy to use. The moment when it is used in some other context, it will start failing. So it is obvious that it is tied to the context.
However pure functions are characterised by being context agnostic. Therefore its inputs are always supplied , and its outputs are always returned or directly referenced in the calling function.
A refactored version given below does the same - making it context agnostic.
export default function App() {

  var url = document.createElement('a');
  url.href = 'http://www.example.com/some/path?name=value#anchor';
  return (
    <>
      <Hello location={url} />
    </>
  );
}

const Hello = ({ location }) => {
  const name = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('name');
  return <div>hello, {name}</div>;
};

Output

Observation
The Hello component in the refactored version now is context agnostic. It can be called with a location object as demoed. It does not depend on the global object location any more. The argument makes it context agnostic.
Theoretically this function Hello now has become referentially transparent. It means the function invocation expression anywhere in the program can be substituted by the respective output.
However the root function App over here is referentially opaque. Since the reference to the global object prevents it being referentially transparent. However, it is not a need for a function like App since it is not meant to be reused.
Therefore the point is this.
Develop functions maximum pure and then move the codes making it impure to the client codes. The following post discusses the same in great detail : Function purity and referential transparency
Citation:
Creating a new Location object in javascript

Thank you for your comment. If you will, you can vote for it, and even confirm it. This will make the content noticeable to others as well.

Sorry, I did not finish.~
The reason I asked this question was that I was trying to adopt react-compiler in my project. But some of the UI was broken. After investigation, I noticed my component imported a function that calculated the current page based on the URL. This breaks the rule that "components and hooks must be pure". Therefore, I was thinking about how should I handle BOM APIs, sessionstorage, ...etc in the components.
I understand your point here is the context of how/where a function/component is used. So do you think it is possible to make ALL components pure?

For example, replace everything depending on location with the hook useLocation from react-router-dom(if this is a dependency)
